# improving performance of a brute force node script by multi-processing/parallel programming

Tags: node.js, multiprocessing, brute-force

I have 5 lists of words. Lets call them `list1`, `list2`, `list3`, `list4`, `list5`. 
There is a superset of words which contains 2048 words.
Each list has either all or some of the words from the superset of words.

Example: 
`superset = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'g', 'z', 'blie']` 
`list1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];` 
`list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];` 
`list3 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];`
`list4 = ['g'];`
`list5 = ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k'];`

The final string `res` is generated by concatenating one word from each list.
For example: `'one' + 'b' + 'f' + 'g' + 'k' = 'onebfgk`

I have a decode function which takes in `res` and outputs a number.
I am interested in finding the string which decodes to a given number: `prize`.

Currently, I am generating all possible combinations of `res`, decoding it and matching it against the given `prize`.
My current node.js script looks like this:

```
var prize = 1234;
var list1 = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var list3 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
var list4 = ['g'];
var list5 = ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k'];
var word1 = '';
var word2 = '';
var word3 = '';
var word4 = '';
var word5 = '';

for (var n = 0; n < list1.length; n++) {
    word1 = list1[n];
    for (var m = 0; m < list2.length; m++) {
        word2 = list2[m];
        for (var o = 0; o < list3.length; o++) {
            word3 = list3[o];
            for (var p = 0; p < list4.length; p++) {
                word4 = list4[p];
                for (var q = 0; q < list5.length; q++) {
                    word5 = list5[q];
                    let res = word1 + word2 + word3 + word4 + word5;
                    if (decode(res) == prize){
                        console.log(res);
                        throw new Error("Found the match. The program will now exit");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am interested in speeding this up.
How can I modify the script to speed it up drastically by having it use GPU or multi-processing/parallel processing or any other way?

I am limited to using node.js because the decode function comes from a node module.

Comment: Do you know how the `decode` function work? Maybe based on that knowledge you could create some `prepare()` function which would filter out words that do not have any chance to be valid? For example, if the `decode` function would only sum the ASCII values of the word and the target value would be `12` then obviously a word like `alamakota` will not be valid ever so it could be filtered out from the input arrays. Do you know what I mean? It won't change the complexity of the solution but may reduce the input size which is *some* improvement.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I understand what you are trying to say but its a blackbox function, and there is no possibility of a pre-filtering. The only improvement I believe possible is to somehow introduce multi-processing/parallel programming to the current script.

Comment: What is arr ?  I don't see it in your code.

Comment: @raven my bad. edited the code.

Comment: Does the  5 list of words is same for every prize ?

Comment: does the order of the array matters?

Comment: @raven the order of words in the `res` is fixed and matters. i.e. it must always be word1+word2+...

Comment: @Rupjyoti the superset of the strings is same and contains 2048 words. the sub lists contains either all or some of the words from the superset

Comment: Depending on what this mystical decode method does, it might not be possible to parallelize it at all. You mention GPU, well, you can't do anything on gpu if it isn't designed for gpu. GPU only does very stupid things, but it does a lot of it very fast. If you cannot control, or do not know what decode does, GPU is out of the question. When it comes to concurrency. This might be possible, or not, depending again on decode. Are you CPU bound? Are you Memory bound? We need to know more than "it's a blackbox function"

Comment: you can at least try to run different portions of the for loop in parallel - building the different "res" strings.  It's up to you to decide based on the # of cores and word list lengths where you want to split up work. 
 Whether decode works in parallel calls or not, if it's black box, all you can do is try. you may wish to look into worker_threads

Comment: NodeJS itself is single threaded so you wont be able to achieve this with high level concepts. You may rely on its architecture to invoke some deeper routines such as forks but NodeJS addons are the way of perform multi-threading properly since you write c++ code that will be executed via N-API or even directly by libuv (NodeJS Asynchronous motor written in C++). [Some reading on the subject](https://medium.com/better-programming/learn-node-js-under-the-hood-37966a20e127). Check the answer below for more insight.

Answer (score 2):

NodeJS is actually written in C++, so if you want to perform some resource intensive work I would suggest you to use [NodeJS addons feature](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html). This is the best way I found to optimise some code that require brute force algorithm in NodeJS.

There are some well done tutorials on the subject that I followed myself for some of my projects :

- [A good entry point](https://apiko.com/blog/node-js-performance-c-addons/)
- [A simple tutorial](https://medium.com/jspoint/a-simple-guide-to-load-c-c-code-into-node-js-javascript-applications-3fcccf54fd32)
- [A more in depth one](https://medium.com/@a7ul/beginners-guide-to-writing-nodejs-addons-using-c-and-n-api-node-addon-api-9b3b718a9a7f)
- [Some examples](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples)

It obviously requires you to know some C++ but I do not think there is a better approach since your goal is pure optimisation and potential for multi-threading operations.

A first approach for your C++ code would be :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool compare(string _str,int seed){
    int val = 0;
    //Generate an int with the string AKA your decode() function
    for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(_str)/sizeof(_str[0]);i++){
            int letter = _str[i];
            val+= letter;
        }
    //Compare the result
    if(val == seed){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

int main()
{
    int prize = 753; //For twoadgk
    string list1[3] = {"one", "two", "three"};
    char list2[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    char list3[3] = {'d', 'e', 'f'};
    char list4[1] = {'g'};
    char list5[4] = {'h', 'i', 'j', 'k'};
    string word1 = "";
    string word2 = "";
    string word3 = "";
    string word4 = "";
    string word5 = "";
        
    for (int n = 0; n < sizeof(list1)/sizeof(list1[0]); n++) {
        word1 = list1[n];
        for (int m = 0; m < sizeof(list2)/sizeof(list2[0]); m++) {
            word2 = list2[m];
            for (int o = 0; o < sizeof(list3)/sizeof(list3[0]); o++) {
                word3 = list3[o];
                for (int p = 0; p < sizeof(list4)/sizeof(list4[0]); p++) {
                    word4 = list4[p];
                    for (int q = 0; q < sizeof(list5)/sizeof(list5[0]); q++) {
                        word5 = list5[q];
                        string res = word1 + word2 + word3 + word4 + word5;
                        if (compare(res,prize)){ //decode(res) == prize
                            cout<< "Found string " << res << " for seed " << prize << endl;
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout<< "Seed could not be match with a string"<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you respect the N-API configuration your nodeJS file should look like :

```
const addon = require('./build/Release/addon');

//Run some c++ code as an add-on of NodeJS
const runAddon = () => addon.main();
runAddon();
```

*Edit : Added examples + C++ code*